# Switch user in PowerShell like "sudo su -" in Unix/Linux

Tags: powershell, user-accounts, administrator

When I am logged in to a Windows server as an Administrator in PowerShell, how do I switch to another user without a typing a password? I am looking for exactly the same feature as `sudo su -` or `su` in Linux.

Comment: you would have to write a custom function, where you work with `new-pssession` and `enter-pssession` and already stored credentials, which you could switch depending on the user you want to be.

Answer (score 6):

You need to write a custom function for this. You could use the following function (below), and put it in your [PowerShell Profile](https://www.howtogeek.com/50236/customizing-your-powershell-profile/).

to use this, you have to use an elevated PowerShell Console.

As you can see, you have a `$user` Parameter, which is set to `adminsystem` by default (use your default username here). In `ValidateSet()` you can say which values are allowed for the `$user` Parameter.

it will then `switch()` depending on your `$user` parameter and read the correct username and password.

Then it will create a credential object, and a pssession as your desired user.

I **do not** recommend using Passwords as plain text in a script! You should follow [this](https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1/) to store your Passwords safely in the script

```
function switch-psuser {
    
    Param(
        [Parameter(Position=0)]
        [ValidateSet("adminsystem","administrator")]
        $User = "adminsystem"
    )

    switch($User)
    {
        'adminsystem'   { $username = "domain\adminsystem" ; $pw = "yyy"}
        'administrator' { $username = "domain\administrator" ; $pw = "zzz" }
    }

    $password = $pw | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
    $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $username,$password
    New-PSSession -Credential $cred | Enter-PSSession
}
```

Example Output:

```
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> switch-psuser
[localhost]: PS C:\Users\adminsystem\Documents> whoami
domain\adminsystem
[localhost]: PS C:\Users\adminsystem\Documents> exit

PS C:\WINDOWS\system32> switch-psuser administrator
[localhost]: PS C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN\Documents> whoami
DOMAIN\administrator
[localhost]: PS C:\Users\Administrator.DOMAIN\Documents> exit
PS C:\WINDOWS\system32>
```

In this example you can see, when supplying no Value for `$user`, it will take your default user. when supplying a username which is in `ValidateSet()` and in `switch()` it will take that one

hope that wasn't too complicated.otherwise just ask :)

Comment: I don't want to store an admin password in a file.

Comment: @WhyWhat There are lots of ways to not store your password in a file, at least not in plain text. e.g https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-2/

Comment: Yes, that is too complicated. Why isn't there a simple `sudo su - <username>`?

Comment: @Snowcrash it's only slightly complicated to setup once, but then it's just as easy. As to why there isn't a simple `sudo` you gotta ask the microsoft engineers :-)

Answer (score 4):

SimonS' response is more convenient but I note that WhyWhat doesn't want to store the password in a file. You can instead use:

```
New-PSSession -Credential $cred | Enter-PSSession
```

Get-Credential, which is spawned when the PSCredential defined on -Credential is not defined, will ask for your username and password in a prompt instead. If you are using Windows Server Core Edition, this prompt is within the Powershell window. The credential is not vetted by your local computer in any way and you can use AD logins in the class Windows format `DOMAIN\username`.

Answer (score -1):

Technically, "sudo su -" means "become root" - so in powershell, this is one equivalent:-

```
Start-Process "C:/Windows/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/powershell.exe" -Verb RunAs
```

It will probably open the UAC control popup to request permission if you've got your PC set up to ask about these things.

It opens a new window unfortunately.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).